# Types Error when run yarn build or tsc commands

Tags: reactjs, typescript, build, tsc

[image]When I try build project or run yarn tsc command I get some types error. Why this can happen?
It looks like it is installing them in the wrong place. But why this can happen.
I can give more detail if you need.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple versions of react type definitions installed. Notice the two different roots of `node_modules` highlighted in the image below:
[image]

## Fix

You need to uninstall one of them otherwise the two definitions will conflict giving errors (as you have noticed).